# Find closest element after another element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to get the first image `<img>` closest to the first `<p>` tag of a webpage using Nokogiri. I will be using the results to display the article synopsis a la the Facebook share link.

The code I am using to get the first `<p>` tag of an article is as follows:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
@title = doc.css('title').text
@content = doc.css('p').first
```

Comment: .... I think your avatar is under copyright

Comment: I'm not sure what **closest** means. Please clarify: (a) If the document is `<p>Hi</p><img>` should the image be found? (b) If the document is `<p>Hi</p><p><img></p>` should the image be found?

Comment: yes, in both cases, the image should be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find the first `<img>` that is inside a `<p>`

If you don't already have/need the `<p>` element, either:

```
first_img_in_p = doc.at_css('p img')
first_img_in_p = doc.at_xpath('//p//img')
```

*Note that instead of [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) or [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) you can just use [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) and let Nokogiri figure out from the string if it is a CSS or XPath expression.*

### Find the first `<img>` that is inside the *first* `<p>`

If you already have the parent node, you can use either of these:

```
first_p     = doc.at('p')  # Better than finding all <p> and then reducing
first_image = first_p.at_css('img')
first_image = first_p.at_xpath('.//img')
```

However, with these answers (unlike the first two) if the first p does not have an image you won't find any image at all.

### Find the first `<img>` in the document

If you really just want the first `<img>` anywhere (which might not be in a `<p>`, or the first `<p>`) then simply do:

```
first_image = doc.at('img')
```

If you want the first image that has at least one `<p>` occurring in the document somewhere before it, but not necessarily as a wrapper for the `<img>`…then say so and I can edit the answer further.

### Find the first `<img>` that has a `<p>` before it (or as an ancestor)

**Edit**: Based on your comment below, I think you want:

```
img = doc.at_xpath('//img[preceding::p or ancestor::p]')
```

This says "Find the first `<img>` in the document that either has a `<p>` occurring somewhere [before it](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AxisSpecifier) (but not an ancestor), or that has as an ancestor `<p>`."

Here are some test cases so you can decide if this is what you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'
[
  %Q{<r><p><img id="a"/></p></r>},
  %Q{<r><img id="z"/><p></p></r>},
  %Q{<r><img id="z"/><p><img id="a"/></p></r>},
  %Q{<r><img id="z"/><p></p><p><img id="a"/></p></r>},
  %Q{<r><p></p><p><img id="a"/></p></r>},
  %Q{<r><img id="z"/><p></p><p><img id="a"/></p></r>},
  %Q{<r><p></p><img id="a"/></r>},
  %Q{<r><img id="z"/><p></p><img id="a"/></r>},
  %Q{<r><p></p><b><c><img id="a"/></c></b></r>},
  %Q{<r><q><p></p></q><b><c><img id="a"/></c></b></r>},
  %Q{<r><p><img id="a"/></p><img id="z"/></r>},
  %Q{<r><p><img id="a"/></p><p><img id="z"/></p></r>},
].each do |xml|
  doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
  img = doc.at_xpath('//img[preceding::p or ancestor::p]')
  puts "%-50s %s" % [ xml, img||NONE ]
end

#=> <r><p><img id="a"/></p></r>                        <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><img id="z"/><p></p></r>                        NONE
#=> <r><img id="z"/><p><img id="a"/></p></r>           <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><img id="z"/><p></p><p><img id="a"/></p></r>    <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><p></p><p><img id="a"/></p></r>                 <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><img id="z"/><p></p><p><img id="a"/></p></r>    <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><p></p><img id="a"/></r>                        <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><img id="z"/><p></p><img id="a"/></r>           <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><p></p><b><c><img id="a"/></c></b></r>          <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><q><p></p></q><b><c><img id="a"/></c></b></r>   <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><p><img id="a"/></p><img id="z"/></r>           <img id="a"/>
#=> <r><p><img id="a"/></p><p><img id="z"/></p></r>    <img id="a"/>
```

Comment: the first part, first_p     = doc.at('p'), works for me, but not for the image. You are right, I would like to know how to get the image closest to the first <p> , either before, after, or inside it.

Comment: I still don't know what "closest" means. Can an image occur before the first `<p>` and should it still be found? See my edit and tell me if that answers your question. (If so, I'd appreciate an upvote and acceptance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the sibling that is an img.
    @content.parent.css('>img')